# How to sort multiple tables based on their values with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have multiple tables in a page and each of them look like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">25</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I need to figure out how to sort the tables (not their rows, the order of tables themselves) based on one their values (for example the values with the class "ei") using Jquery. All I could find was how to sort the rows of the table not the tables themselves.

Example:

Based on the values with class "ei", I want to rearrange this:

```
<table id="2135">
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">13</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="2131">
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">50</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="2129">
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">25</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Into this:

```
<table id="2135">
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">13</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="2129">
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">25</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="2131">
<tr>
    <td class= "fi">102,215,231.02</td>
    <td class= "se">215,321</td>
    <td class= "th">1,002</td>
    <td class= "fo">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class= "fiv">2,251</td>
    <td class= "si">55,544,444</td>
    <td class= "sev">123,000.25</td>
    <td class= "ei">50</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: How do you want the tables to be triggered into activating?

Comment: Are they all siblings of the same parent? That'll make a pretty big difference.

Comment: If it is only done once, it would be better to do this arranging of tables on the server.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist With a radio list.

Comment: @squint They are all in the same container div.

Comment: @Mottie The tables need to be changed on the users browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort `.ei` elements but replace their closest `<table>` parents:

```
var eis = $('.ei').sort(function(a,b){
  return $(a).html() - $(b).html();
});

eis.each(function(i){
    $('body').append($(this).closest('table'))
})
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocdy1wx7/2/)